# Given two positive numbers $b,\,c$. Prove $\left ( \frac{3}{b}- 1 \right )(3- b)^{2}+ \left ( \frac{b}{c}- 1 \right )(b- c)^{2}+ (c- 1)^{3}\geqq 0$ .

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, substitution, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way

Given two positive numbers $b,\,c$. Prove $\left ( \dfrac{3}{b}- 1 \right )(3- b)^{2}+ \left ( \dfrac{b}{c}- 1 \right )(b- c)^{2}+ (c- 1)^{3}\geqq 0$ .
*My problem is given a solution by user dragonheart6 (AoPS), I tried a way without using computer decompostion! He is so into using sos with the form* $\dfrac{1}{q^{2}}\sum\limits_{i= 1}^{m} f_{i}g_{i}^{2}$*, I will post my solution for this soon!*
$$354816000(b+ 1)^{2}bc.\,\left [ \left ( \frac{3}{b}- 1 \right )(3- b)^{2}+ \left ( \frac{b}{c}- 1 \right )(b- c)^{2}+ (c- 1)^{3} \right ]=$$
$$= 55440\,b^{2}(80\,bc^{2}- 97\,b^{2}- 80\,bc- 40\,c^{2}+ 200\,c)^{2}+ 1836000(16\,b^{3}- 32\,b^{2}c+ 9\,bc^{2}- 8\,bc)^{2}$$
$$+ 39424000\,c(b^{2}+ 3\,bc- 3\,b- 12)^{2}+ 38500(-\,48\,b^{2}c+ 151\,bc^{2}+ 96\,b^{2}- 288\,bc)^{2}+$$
$$+ 2772000\,bc(16\,bc- 23\,b- 16\,c+ 24)^{2}+ 1182720\,b(11\,b^{2}- 10\,bc+ 15\,c^{2}- 35\,c)^{2}+$$
$$+ 184800 bc(-\,59\,b+ 120)^{2}+ 231 b(151\,b^{2}- 1760\,bc+ 3200\,c)^{2}+ 7884800 c(-\,8\,b^{2}+ 15\,b+ 9)^{2}$$
$$+ 19219200\,b^{3}c+ 3379200\,c(7\,b^{2}- 31)^{2}+ 126\,b(553\,b^{2}- 880\,bc)^{2}+$$
$$+16896000\,c+ 18711000\,b^{2}c^{4}+ 7700(48\,b^{2}c- 85\,bc^{2})^{2}+ 1088955\,b^{5}\geqq 0$$

Comment: $\left ( \dfrac{2}{b}- 1 \right )(2- b)^{2}+ \left ( \dfrac{b}{c}- 1 \right )(b- c)^{2}+ (c- 1)^{3}\geqq 0$ is also true, but I have no a nice solution.

Comment: Thanks for your interest a real lot !

Comment: I saw the open one in AoPS, I really like it ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $1=a$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\frac{(3a-b)^3}{b}+\frac{(b-c)^3}{c}+\frac{(c-a)^3}{a}\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$\frac{(3a-b)^3}{b}+\frac{(b-c)^3}{c}+\frac{(c-a)^3}{a}>\frac{(2a-b)^3}{b}+\frac{(b-c)^3}{c}+\frac{(c-a)^3}{a}\geq0,$$
where a proof of the last inequality see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1863562p12626347

Comment: +75 Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, the respect to KaiRain. My solution of this problem is very ugly.